# User Control in Window phone 8.1

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm try create Application where i required to use User Control.I'm already created **MainPage.xaml** here code below

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
```

And User Control define below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.UserControls"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Height="50" Width="427">


<Canvas x:Name="SpatialCanvas" Background="Wheat">
    <Border 
        x:Name="dragSelectionBorder"
        BorderBrush="Blue"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Background="LightBlue"
        CornerRadius="1"
        Opacity="0.5"
        />
</Canvas>
```

How To call this user control to **MainPage.xaml** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"`, this is the reference to your Namespace for your MainPage and your custom UserControl.

So to use it on the MainPage

```XAML
<local:USER_CONTROL_NAME/>
```

---

In your case your UserControl is named `UserControls`  (you should reconsider renaming that)

so finally to use your custom control

```
<local:UserControls/>
```

Comment: I use this                                                                                            <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="test.MainPage"    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <local:UserControls Name="usercontrl">
    </local:UserControls>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>       But it's not showing the custome control

Comment: @diy that should work if you defined your `local` like you did in the question.  I don't know what you're using `Name` for, you have no Binding for it nor did you post any code to show otherwise.

Comment: @diy If the answer was sufficient enough for you, please mark it as solved.  That way it doesn't appear on my feed, thanks.  Welcome to SO and Windows Phone.